# Find each div with a specific class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find each `.question` that does not have a class of `.skip-1` and hide it.

```
$('.skip-1-hook').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question').hasClass('skip-1')) {
    $(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question').hide();
 });
```

I guess it would be nice to put `$(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question')` into a variable too but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: aren't you missing a close bracket on the if?

Comment: `$(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question:not(.skip-1)').hide();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('.skip-1-hook').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question:not(.skip-1)').hide();
    //if you want to target all .question elements then use
    //$('.question').not('.skip-1').hide()
});
```

Comment: @TravisJ if it is about raw speed then http://jsperf.com/not-versus-filter-jquery/2

Comment: The test I linked was incorrect, thanks for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `not()` selector of jquery for this purpose:

```
$(".question:not(.skip-1)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `:not()` selector you can hide your elements this way:

```
$(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question:not(.skip-1)').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) or [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to filter out the elements with the class.

```
$(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question').not(".skip-1").hide();
```

or

```
$(this).parent('.question').siblings('.question:not(.skip-1)').hide();
```